# Compare products in sidebar of category pages not showing when no products

Tags: sidebar, compare

I am working on http://urbantrend.co.in/test/ project. And In sidebar on category pages compare products disappears if there is no product http://urbantrend.co.in/test/index.php/womens.html. If i have some products in compare then that block will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Kishor,your compare product **block is render every time at category page**   ,but on that **block's class template file**,you may **have a condition** which is show block block-list block-compare block whenever you have any product in compare.

Basically this template file location  may be `app/design/frontent/Your_Package/Your_theme/tempate/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml`.may on this file you have a condition like:

```
<?php if ($_items): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-compare">
```

Comment: Yes i can see that but same time i have else block where following code is exist
<?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items to compare.') ?></p>.
So, what could be the solution.

Comment: yes, that could be solution ..